# Getting relocation error on Ubuntu 18.04 for wkhtmltopdf tool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, libraries

My project need a tool called `wkhtmltopdf` on Ubuntu. I have installed it successfully. It's displaying proper version with command `wkhtmltopdf --version`.

When java code tries to access this tool, getting below error stream.

```
wkhtmltopdf: relocation error: wkhtmltopdf: symbol CRYPTO_num_locks version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
```

**Note** : I have installed `wkhtmltox_0.12.1.3-1~bionic_amd64.deb` first but was getting different errors with it and I found it's not compatible with latest Ubuntu, so I have installed `wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.xenial_amd64.deb` now and getting above error.